# In JSONSchema, how do I validate a schema to have at least one of two properties?

Tags: json, jsonschema

Now there are a few questions already asking for similar things, but I couldn't find one that matches exactly what I want.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "title": "Example schema",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "youtubeLink": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\\.)?youtu(?:be\\.com\/watch\\?v=|\\.be\/)([\\w\\-\\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\\w\\?‌​=]*)?"
        },
        "assetFile": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "dependencies": {
        "assetFile": {
            "not": {
                "required": [
                    "youtubeLink"
                ]
            }
        },
        "youtubeLink": {
            "not": {
                "required": [
                    "assetFile"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In the example you can see two properties and at one of them is required, no more, no less. At the moment you can't give in both properties, but you can give in none. I also want there to be no additional properties (which is already done). I know that it can be done by specifying a minimal amount of properties, but does seem hacky if you have a more complicated schema.

And if it is possible, I would also prefer there to be a default property with a default value, if none of the two props are given.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I finally got something to work, even with the default. But is there any shorter way to do this?

Yes, you can use [`oneOf`](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#oneof)

https://runkit.com/embed/wqbge78zzxb6

```js
const Ajv = require("ajv")
const ajv = new Ajv({allErrors: true})

const schema = {
  title: 'Example schema',
  oneOf: [
    {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        youtubeLink: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      },
      required: [
        'youtubeLink'
      ],
      additionalProperties: false
    },
    {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        assetFile: {
          type: 'string'
        }
      },
      required: [
        'assetFile'
      ],
      additionalProperties: false
    },
    {
      type: 'object',
      properties: {
        foo: {
          type: 'string',
          default: 'hello'
        }
      },
      additionalProperties: false
    }
  ]
}


const validate = ajv.compile(schema)

test({youtubeLink: 'hello'}) // valid
test({assetFile: 'bar'}) // valid
test({assetFile: 'bar', youtubeLink: 'hello'}) // INVALID
test({}) // default value

function test(data) {
  const valid = validate(data)
  if (valid) console.log("Valid!")
  else console.log("Invalid: " + ajv.errorsText(validate.errors))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `oneOf` to express this very cleanly. `oneOf` asserts that one and only one of the given schemas must be valid for the schema to validate.

```json
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "youtubeLink": {},
    "assetFile": {}
  },
  "additionalProperties": false,
  "oneOf": [
    { "required": ["youtubeLink"] },
    { "required": ["assetFile"] }
  ]
}
```

- If you only have "youtubeLink", `/oneOf/0` will pass and `/oneOf/1` will fail. (PASS)
- If you only have "assetFile", `/oneOf/0` will fail and `/oneOf/1` will pass. (PASS)
- If you have both, `/oneOf/0` will pass and `/oneOf/1` will pass. (FAIL)
- If you have none, `/oneOf/0` will fail and `/oneOf/1` will fail. (FAIL)

Answer (score 0):

I finally got something to work, even with the default. But is there any shorter way to do this? I only came to this result after learning JSON Schemas and trying out a few hours, so there must be something shorter.

```json
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema",
    "title": "Config file validation",
    "description": "validation schema of the config.json file",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "youtubeLink": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "http(?:s?):\/\/(?:www\\.)?youtu(?:be\\.com\/watch\\?v=|\\.be\/)([\\w\\-\\_]*)(&(amp;)?‌​[\\w\\?‌​=]*)?"
        },
        "assetFile": {
            "type": "string",
            "pattern": "^(/)?([^/\\0\n]+(/)?)+\\.(mp3)$"
        }
    },
    "additionalProperties": false,
    "if": {
        "not": {
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "required": [
                        "youtubeLink"
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "required": [
                        "assetFile"
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    },
    "then": {
        "properties": {
            "youtubeLink": {
                "default": "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
            }
        }
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "assetFile": {
            "not": {
                "required": [
                    "youtubeLink"
                ]
            }
        },
        "youtubeLink": {
            "not": {
                "required": [
                    "assetFile"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```